# "findOne is not a function" with jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize mock v5 to mock User model.

```
// user.test.js
import User from "../models/user"; // original user model class

jest.mock("../models/user", () => () => {
    const SequelizeMock = require("sequelize-mock-v5");
    const dbMock = new SequelizeMock();
    return dbMock.define("User", { id: 111, username: "myusername" });
});

test("blabla", async () => {
    const r = await User.findOne({ where: { id:1 }});
    // expectations here
});
```

This gives me

```
TypeError: _user.default.findOne is not a function
```

Here is the original User model which I am trying to mock.

```
// /models/user.js
export default class User extends Model {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second `factory` parameter of `jest.mock()` should return the mock object instead of an arrow function.

Try:

`models/user.js`:

```js
import { Model } from 'sequelize';
export default class User extends Model {}
```

`user.test.js`:

```js
import User from './models/user'; // original user model class

jest.mock('./models/user', () => {
  const SequelizeMock = require('sequelize-mock');
  const dbMock = new SequelizeMock();
  return dbMock.define('User', { id: 111, username: 'myusername' });
});

test('blabla', async () => {
  const r = await User.findOne({ where: { id: 1 } });
  expect(r).toEqual(
    expect.objectContaining({
      id: expect.any(Number),
      username: 'myusername',
      createdAt: expect.any(Date),
      updatedAt: expect.any(Date),
    }),
  );
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  src/examples/stackoverflow/67794412/user.test.js
  ✓ blabla (4ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.371s, estimated 4s
```

package versions:

```json
"sequelize-mock": "^0.10.2",
"sequelize": "^5.21.3",
"jest": "^29.5.0",
```